# Why aren't all bigrams created in gensim's `Phrases` tool?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, n-gram, word-embedding

I have created a bigram model using gensim and the try to get the bigram sentences but it's not picking all bigram sentences why?

```py
from gensim.models.phrases import Phrases, Phraser
phrases = Phrases(sentences, min_count=1, threshold=1)
bigram_model = Phraser(phrases)
sent = [u'the', u'mayor', u'of', u'new', u'york', u'was', u'there']
print(bigram_model[sent])
[u'the', u'mayor', u'of', u'new_york', u'was', u'there']
```

Can anyone explain how to get all bigrams.

## Why only 'new_york' not 'the_mayor' and others?

Comment: Because "New York" is a bigram and "the mayor" isn't?

Comment: @AKX the question is how `Phrases` decides "new york" is a bigram and "the mayor" is not; how can they be different when `min_count=1, threshold=1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Phrases` algorithm decides which word-pairs to promote to bigrams by a statistical analysis, which compares the base frequencies of each word individually with their frequency together.

So, some word-pairs will pass this test, and be combined, and others won't. If you're not getting the pairings you expect, then you can tune the algorithm somewhat using the `Phrases` class options, including `threshold`, `min_count`, and at least one alternate scoring-mechanism.

But, even maximally tuned, it won't typically create all the phrases that we, as natural-language speakers, would perceive – as it knows nothing of grammar, or the actually logically-related entities of the world. It only knows frequency statistics in the training text.

So there will be pairings it misses we'd see as natural & desirable, and pairings it creates we'd see as illogical. Still, even with these unaesthetic pairings – creating text that doesn't look right to people – the transformed text can often work better in certain downstream classification or information-retrieval tasks.

If you really just wanted all possible bigrams, that'd be a much more simple text transformation, not requiring the multiple-passes & internal statistics-collection of gensim's `Phrases`.

But also, if you do want to use gensim's `Phrases` technique, it will only perform well when it has a lot of training data.  Toy-sized texts of just a few dozen words –or even many tens-of-thousands of words – won't give good results. You'd want millions to tens-of-millions of training words to have some chance of it really detecting statistically-valid word-pairings.